# Kerberos PKINIT - No matching entry found preauth (pkinit) verify failure: Certificate mismatch

Tags: openssl, centos7, kerberos, freeipa

I have installed a FreeIPA master server including Kerberos. Furthermore I have one client server, enrolled in FreeIPA, to test the PKINIT feature of Kerberos. All servers run on CentOS7.
A testuser exists in FreeIPA and this user is also listed in the one and only existing realm, when using `list_principals` in `kadmin` as testuser@REALMNAME.

`getprinc testuser` also gives `Attributes: REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH`.

I have created kdc and client certificates strictly following the documentation: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/admin/pkinit.html. They have been signed by my own CA, whose certificate is also present on the client and the master.

The [realm] config on the master is as follows:

```
[realms]
 TEST.INTERN = {
  kdc = XXX:88
  master_kdc = XXX:88
  admin_server = XXX:749
  default_domain = test.intern
  pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/krb/ca.pem
  pkinit_identity = FILE:/etc/krb/kdc.pem,/etc/krb/kdckey.pem
  allow_pkinit = yes
  module = pkinit:/usr/lib64/krb5/plugins/preauth/pkinit.so
}
```

with XXX being the master servers FQDN. Furthermore, the client is configured as follows:

```
[realms]
  TEST.INTERN = {
    kdc = XXX:88
    master_kdc = XXX:88
    admin_server = XXX:749
    kpasswd_server = XXX:464
    default_domain = test.intern
    pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/krb/ca.pem
    pkinit_identities = FILE:/etc/krb/client.pem,/etc/krb/clientkey.pem
  }
```

AFAIK I should be able to perform `kinit testuser` on the client to get a Kerberos Ticket without entering a password.

Unfortunately, executing  `env KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stdout kinit -V testuser` yields:

```
[2988] 1614772826.172614: Getting initial credentials for testuser@TEST.INTERN
[2988] 1614772826.172616: Sending unauthenticated request
[2988] 1614772826.172617: Sending request (170 bytes) to TEST.INTERN
[2988] 1614772826.172618: Resolving hostname XXX
[2988] 1614772826.172619: Initiating TCP connection to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172620: Sending TCP request to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172621: Received answer (298 bytes) from stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172622: Terminating TCP connection to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172623: Response was from master KDC
[2988] 1614772826.172624: Received error from KDC: -1765328359/Additional pre-authentication required
[2988] 1614772826.172627: Preauthenticating using KDC method data
[2988] 1614772826.172628: Processing preauth types: PA-PK-AS-REQ (16), PA-PK-AS-REP_OLD (15), PA-PK-AS-REQ_OLD (14), PA-FX-FAST (136), PA-ETYPE-INFO2 (19), PA-PKINIT-KX (147), PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP (2), PA-FX-C
OKIE (133)
[2988] 1614772826.172629: Selected etype info: etype aes256-cts, salt ""@0.X)+A92ZBJ*5T", params ""
[2988] 1614772826.172630: Received cookie: MIT
[2988] 1614772826.172631: Preauth module pkinit (147) (info) returned: 0/Success
[2988] 1614772826.172632: PKINIT loading CA certs and CRLs from FILE
[2988] 1614772826.172633: PKINIT client computed kdc-req-body checksum 9/80ADD1F631A328C4895D0B822F96608C303E6743
[2988] 1614772826.172635: PKINIT client making DH request
[2988] 1614772826.172636: Preauth module pkinit (16) (real) returned: 0/Success
[2988] 1614772826.172637: Produced preauth for next request: PA-FX-COOKIE (133), PA-PK-AS-REQ (16)
[2988] 1614772826.172638: Sending request (3475 bytes) to TEST.INTERN
[2988] 1614772826.172639: Resolving hostname XXX
[2988] 1614772826.172640: Initiating TCP connection to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172641: Sending TCP request to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172642: Received answer (167 bytes) from stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172643: Terminating TCP connection to stream XXX_IP:88
[2988] 1614772826.172644: Response was from master KDC
[2988] 1614772826.172645: Received error from KDC: -1765328318/Certificate mismatch
kinit: Certificate mismatch while getting initial credentials
```

The master server confirms this. The /var/log/krb5kdc.log yields:

```
Mar 03 13:01:10 XXX krb5kdc[80746](info): Doing certauth authorize for [testuser@TEST.INTERN]
Mar 03 13:01:10 XXX krb5kdc[80746](info): Got cert filter [(userCertificate;binary=...
Mar 03 13:01:10 XXX krb5kdc[80746](info): No matching entry found
Mar 03 13:01:10 XXX krb5kdc[80746](info): preauth (pkinit) verify failure: Certificate mismatch
```

At this point, I really don't know, why this failure occurs. The certificates have been created striclty following the documentation linked above.
When examining the certificates with `openssl asn1parse -in certificate.pem -strparse OFFSET`, with the according offset, I get for the SubjectAltName, othername section:

```
openssl asn1parse -dump -in ../client/client.pem -strparse 815
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  48 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  46 cons: cont [ 0 ]
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   6 prim: OBJECT            :1.3.6.1.5.2.2
   12:d=2  hl=2 l=  36 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   14:d=3  hl=2 l=  34 cons: SEQUENCE
   16:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   18:d=5  hl=2 l=  11 prim: GENERALSTRING
      0000 - 54 45 53 54 2e 49 4e 54-45 52 4e                  TEST.INTERN
   31:d=4  hl=2 l=  17 cons: cont [ 1 ]
   33:d=5  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SEQUENCE
   35:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   37:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
   40:d=6  hl=2 l=   8 cons: cont [ 1 ]
   42:d=7  hl=2 l=   6 cons: SEQUENCE
   44:d=8  hl=2 l=   4 prim: GENERALSTRING
      0000 - 74 65 73 74 75 73 65 72                                       testuser
```

for the client certificate and

```
openssl asn1parse -dump -in kdc.pem -strparse 832
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  63 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  61 cons: cont [ 0 ]
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   6 prim: OBJECT            :1.3.6.1.5.2.2
   12:d=2  hl=2 l=  51 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   14:d=3  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE
   16:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   18:d=5  hl=2 l=  11 prim: GENERALSTRING
      0000 - 54 45 53 54 2e 49 4e 54-45 52 4e                  TEST.INTERN
   31:d=4  hl=2 l=  32 cons: cont [ 1 ]
   33:d=5  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE
   35:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   37:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
   40:d=6  hl=2 l=  23 cons: cont [ 1 ]
   42:d=7  hl=2 l=  21 cons: SEQUENCE
   44:d=8  hl=2 l=   6 prim: GENERALSTRING
      0000 - 6b 72 62 74 67 74                                 krbtgt
   52:d=8  hl=2 l=  11 prim: GENERALSTRING
      0000 - 54 45 53 54 2e 49 4e 54-45 52 4e                  TEST.INTERN
```

for the kdc certificate

Currently I'm quite lost on why this isn't working.

PS: I've reaplced the real master server's FQDN with XXX and it's IP with XXX_IP.

Comment: I think you are mixing up KDC standalone use-case and FreeIPA deployment. Please see here for more details: https://www.freeipa.org/page/V4/Kerberos_PKINIT

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you please be more specific which part am I missing here? Neither do I use the dogtag PKI, since I have an external one, nor the DNS, NTP or any ohter freeIPA component besides the directory server and the KDC.
I just want to utilize freeIPA for user/group adminstration and access control.

Comment: I'll put together a quick blog post and share it here once it's ready.

Comment: Can you also show the full user certificate and the LDAP user object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog post I put together that should give you an idea how to setup Kerberos PKINIT preauthentication mechanism to authenticate an IPA user with a X.509 certificate:

[PKINIT with IPA and user certificates](https://tscherf.github.io/freeipa-and-pkinit.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. I didn't know, that you have to add the certificate to the freeIPA user.

Comment: Glad it now works for you. Please note that you do not necessarily have to store the certificate in LDAP. You can also use [SSSD/IPA certificate matching and mapping feature](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd.sssd/design_pages/matching_and_mapping_certificates.html).